# windows cannot access the specified device path or file

Tags: windows, windows-7

today, i see any shortcut in my western digital usb external hard(500GB) for all files and i dont see my files. after click in this shortcut i see this error :

```
windows cannot access the specified device path or file. you may not have the appropriate permission to access the item.
```

how to fix this error? and how to access to my files?

Screen 1:

[image]

Screen 2:

[image]

Screen 3:(properties)

[image]

Screen 4:

[image]

target is:

```
C:\Windows\system32\rundll32.exe ~$WND.FAT,crys desktop.ini gmciyeta fubqxmsj " "
```

Comment: Have you tried plugging the device into another PC or another port on your PC?

Comment: Yes, I test This in my laptop, PC, Another PC. i see this error in all.

Comment: That's an awfully strange "Target" you've got there. I suppose that's the point? Sounds like some type of corruption. I advise doing a full backup of your data if it's still possible.

Comment: @CodyGray: yes i think any virus or trojan create this shortcut! but how to backup from my files? i cant see orginal files!

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, the only suggestion I can come up with - having read the comments - is that you download and burn a bootable Linux CD such as [Knoppix](http://knoppix.net/).

Boot from the CD/DVD and only then plug in the external drive. See if Linux can handle it. This will deal with any issues or malware on Windows.

If you get similar problems with Linux, it is almost certainly a corrupted drive. Fixing *that* is likely to require some cost. I generally recommend getting a copy of [Spinrite](http://www.grc.com) which fixes a great many disk issues. However, the cost is around USD90 I'm afraid. Still cheaper than sending the disk to a recovery service if it the only copy of the data. I used this method just last year to recover a laptop with an apparently dying hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

It may because of your user. You may logged in by different user.Try root user.

Comment: I am having trouble understanding your answer. Care to clarity/add detail?

Comment: You may not have root permission and you need to logged in by root permission.You may need to modify your windows variables or may it be solved by modifying permissions by right click `>security>advance>permissions` and make change permissions for such files.

Comment: Windows doesn't have a 'root' account - you might mean the administrator account?

Comment: yeas I mean the admin acount.http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/enable-the-hidden-administrator-account-on-windows-vista